# Does realm.io has something similar as "awakefromfetch" and "willSave"

Tags: ios, realm

Looking into Realm.io and trying to figure out of how to store customer types like CMTime, CMTimeRange, I'm using to store them in NSData in CoreData based on these ideas;

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001919-SW1

I would like just before the object gets saved, to store all the customer types in an NSData blob.

Answer (score 0):

Realm does not currently have an equivalent to `awakeFromFetch` or `willSave`, but you can approximate that functionality by using computed (unpersisted) properties.